# iPhone - Accessing superviews methods?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, methods, call, subview

So essentially I'm inserting "startViewController" into "mainViewController" now of course I can access startViewControllers methods from mainViewController but I was wondering how to do the opposite? Occasionally startViewController will need to call something in mainViewController and I was just wondering how I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add an ivar of your mainViewController to your startViewController and set this when showing the view.

Or you can design a nice clean protocol, and make one view the delegate of the other.

Comment: Thanks! I've never heard of this solution before. Any tips on how to go about doing it?

Comment: Add a variable in your StartViewController.h file, make it a property and set it somewhen :-)

Comment: So presumably I do this?
startViewController.h:
"mainViewController *variable;
@property (nonatomic,retain) mainViewController *variable"

startViewController.m:
"#import "mainViewController.h"
@synthesize variable;

[variable method];"

Comment: Here's a very good answer on how to implement a clean protocol/delegate solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073837/accessing-a-method-on-a-views-superview-what-is-uiviewcontrollerwrapperview