# Accessing a method on a views superview - What is UIViewControllerWrapperView?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

My problem is a follows

I have a UIViewController subclass which holds a UISegmentedController and four tableviews that I layed out in interface builder.

```
@interface MultiTableHoldingView : UIViewController{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet DataTV *dsDataTV;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet EnviroTV *dsEnvironmentTV;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet LocationTV *dsLocationTV;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet Note_AnimalTV *dsNoteAnimal;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *diveElementSegmentController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) DiveSite* currentSite;

- (IBAction)diveElementSegmentControllerDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)sender;

-(void) setFreshWaterColor;
-(void) setSaltwaterColor;

@end
```

setFreshWaterColor and setSaltWaterColour just set the background colour properties of the MultiTableHoldingView instances UIView and the four tableviews it contains. Both these method work fine when called from MultiTableHoldingView's viewDidLoad  method. Heres one of them

```
-(void) setSaltwaterColor{

    DLog(@"in set salt water colour");
    self.view.backgroundColor= SaltWaterColor;
    _dsLocationTV.backgroundColor=SaltWaterColor;
    _dsDataTV.backgroundColor=SaltWaterColor;
    _dsEnvironmentTV.backgroundColor=SaltWaterColor;
    _dsNoteAnimal.backgroundColor=SaltWaterColor;
```

}

The other is the same except sets to FreshWaterColor - both are #define i have set up.

I use the segmentedController to turn the hidden properties of the various tableviews on and off. All nice and simple. The tableviews are pulling in their data. Working fine.

When selecting one of my tableview cells on one of the tableViews I want to change the background colour of both my tableview ( in fact all of my tableviews ) and the UIView that is the superview

```
self.superview.backgroundColor = FreshWaterColor;
```

works fine for reaching back and changing the instance of MultiTableHoldingView views background property but I want to call the instance of  MultiTableHoldingView's    setFreshWaterColor   and  setSaltwaterColor methods.

I have imported MultiTableHoldingViews header into the relevant tableview (EnviroTV), so it knows about it its superviews methods. But if I try to call  either of the two methods on self.superview the methods do not show up and if i type them in full I get an the following error

no visible interface for 'UIView' shows the selector 'setFreshWaterColor'

So i checked what kind of object the superview was and its a "class of superview UIViewControllerWrapperView"

I search on this and its apparently "

This is a private view used by the framework. You're not supposed to modify it or whatsoever."

I'm obviously missing something here - how should i call the method on the instance of MultiTableHoldingView ?

Thanks in advance

Simon

Doh - its just delegation as danypata mentions in the comments - i've posted exactly how I did this as an answer below. Tried to make it as clear as possible how delegation works

Comment: Cast the view returned by the `superview` to your MultiTableHoldingView calass. Like this `MultiTableHoldingView *custom view = (MultiTableHoldingView *) aView.superview;` This will only work if the view returned by the aView.superview is of type `MultiTableHoldingView`

Comment: I think your comment is not completed:))

Comment: Cheers danypata - To do this i obviously need to import the MultiTableHoldingView.h into the tableClass i'm using so i can cast against it  but this leads then to 2 problems on compile with the  MultiTableHoldingView.h file  list above on the following line        @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet EnviroTV *dsEnvironmentTV;       it tells me first that there is a Parse issue with unknown type name 'enviroTV  and a semantic issue  property with retain or strong attribute must be an object type. Any ideas? Is this an issue with the two classes referencing each other ?

Comment: First of all I think you should edit your entire question and use the proper naming because I think you are making a confusion between UIView and UIViewController and I think I misunderstood your question. Please edit your question and I will have another look when it's ready ;)

Comment: sorry about that  yes MultiTableHoldingView is a UIViewController not a UIView so its the instance of the UIViewController that i'm trying to get hold of not the UIView that comes on a standard UIViewController ill try to edit my queton to make things clearer

Comment: I think I know what you are trying, you want to access a viewcontroller's methods using your tableView superview. Well this is impossible to do, at least in this way, what you need is `delegates`. Check the SO or google for delegate tutorials.

Comment: Cheer danypata - you are right of course delegation was the right approach - i just went off-piste because i could get at and set the background colour of the superview and just assumed i should somehow just be able to fire i=the instance of the class the uiview was on 's method  then discover this UIViewControllerWrapperView threw me complete off path. - not enough sleep last night - cheers

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted one ;)

Comment: Cant do that til tomorrow - but i will - thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

### THE SOLUTION

Step one - get more sleep before coding .

This really is basic objective-c stuff - I just went off at a tangent, looking for someway else to do it, getting confused by my discovery of UIViewControllerWrapperView along the way.

The solution, as danypata rightly suggests in the comments, is to use delegate -a common design pattern in Objective-C  - just like you do, for example, when you use another class to supply tableview data

As I've been a numpty and wasted hours of my time today I'll try and make the 'how' clear for other relative newbies or people having an off day and not thinking straight.

In my case I set this up as follows

In my subview class's interface file - EnviroTV.h  - I define the following protocol just before the @interface declaration

```
@protocol EnviroTVProtocol <NSObject>


-(void) setFreshWaterColor;
-(void) setSaltwaterColor;


@end
```

Then in the @interface section of the same file I add a property of type id which must conform the protocol I just declared .

```
@property (nonatomic, strong ) id<EnviroTVProtocol> colorChangeDelegate;
```

You make the type an id - a generic object - as you really don't care what kind of object is going to act as your delegate just that it implement the methods that you need it to run. When an object declares itself to implement a protocol its just promising to implement the method(s) that are required by the protocol

So, when I want to  run the methods on the superviews class I call

[self.colorChangeDelegate setFreshWaterColor];

Or

[self.colorChangeDelegate setSaltWaterColor];

The final piece of the delegation pattern is to go into the class thats going to be the delegate (in this case my MultiTableHoldingView class ) and state that it conforms to the protocol

I do this in the MultiTableHoldingView.h file

Changing this line :

```
@interface MultiTableHoldingView : UIViewController
```

into  this line :

```
@interface MultiTableHoldingView : UIViewController <EnviroTVProtocol>
```

means this class promises to implement all the required methods of the EnviroTVProtocol.

Luckily I had already written the two methods. So when I compiled it ran correctly

Newbies - don't be afraid of delegation - its awesome and not as complex as you first imagine it to be

Meanwhile, if anyone can explain what  UIViewControllerWrapperView is .....